# keyboardShortcut modifier is not working with a custom ButtonStyle

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

In SwiftUI on macOS you have a modifier to enable shortcuts for a specific control. For example:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Print message") {
            print("Hello World!")
        }
        .keyboardShortcut("p", modifiers: [.command, .shift])
    }
}
```

If you run the app and press CMD+SHIFT+p you'll see "Hello world" on your console.
Unfortunately as soon as I specify a custom style for the button, the shortcut no longer works:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button("Print message") {
            print("Hello World!")
        }
        .buttonStyle(MyButtonStyle())
        .keyboardShortcut("p", modifiers: [.command, .shift])
    }
}

struct MyButtonStyle: ButtonStyle {
    func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(.red)
    }
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: What if you switch the order around,  calling `keyboardShort` first, and then `buttonStyle` on the result?

Comment: @Alexander unfortunately nothing changes.

Comment: Works as expected on macOS 11.2, Xcode 12.4.

Comment: @pawello2222 Mmh... weird. I’m on Xcode 11.4 and macOS 11.2.1 and I’m experiencing the issue. The same for a guy I know. Did you try exactly the snippet I posted above?

Comment: @matteopuc Yes, I've tried the code above (without any modifications) - looks like this might be a bug of macOS 11.2.1.

Comment: @matteopuc I've just tried on macOS 11.2.1 - everything works.

Comment: I'm on macOS 11.2.3 and it's not working for me either. Do you found a workaround @matteopuc?

Comment: @LeonardoEmilioDominguez not yet, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm on macOS 11.6 and have the same issue. The only solution I found is this one https://www.soudegesu.com/en/post/swift/keyboard-shortcut-with-button-style-on-osx/ but it's not ideal for sure